# Set property of vba class with object reference

Tags: vba

I have a class module, named `Normal`, in VBA with the following code:

```
Private mLine As LineElement

Public Property Get Line() As LineElement
    Line = mLine
End Property

Public Property Set Line(ByRef vLine As LineElement)
    mLine = vLine
End Property
```

This class is used by the following code:

```
Sub Run
    Dim Line As LineElement
    Set Line = New LineElement

    Dim Norm As Normal
    Set Norm = New Normal
    Set Norm.Line = Line 'FAILS here with "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set"'
End Sub
```

Also, if I change the code in the `Normal` class module to:

```
Private mLine As LineElement

Public Property Get Line() As LineElement
    Line = mLine
End Property

Public Sub SetLine(ByRef vLine As LineElement) 'changed from property to sub'
    mLine = vLine
End Property
```

and the failing line to

```
Norm.SetLine( Line )
```

I get an "Object does not support this property or method" error.  What exactly am I doing wrong in both of these cases?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private mLine As LineElement

Public Property Get Line() As LineElement
    Set Line = mLine
End Property

Public Property Set Line(ByRef vLine As LineElement)
    Set mLine = vLine   'Note the added Set keyword in this line'
End Property
```

Comment: d'oh so simple! Thanks for the help.  (I'm hating the VBA editor that it doesn't provide more assistance for simple things like this)

Comment: double d'oh! Spent hours chasing cannot assign to ActiveX. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

Both properties must have "Set" keyword

```
Private mLine As LineElement

Public Property Get Line() As LineElement
    Set Line = mLine 'Set keyword must be present
End Property

Public Property Set Line(vLine As LineElement) ' ByRef is the default in VBA
    Set mLine = vLine 'Set keyword must be present
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private mLine As new LineElement

Public Property Get Line() As LineElement
    Set Line = mLine
End Property

Public Property Set Line(ByRef vLine As LineElement)
    Set mLine = vLine
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

The Set statement is used to make a reference of an object to an object variable. You don't have to use the Set keyword, if you are dealing with primitive and native built-in types such as integer, double, string and so on. Here you are dealing with an object of type LineElement.