# Accessing a private field in class module

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simplified class module clXXX....

```
':: backing field
Private fTemplateBk As Excel.Workbook

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::
'::
':: constructor
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::
'::
':: properties
Property Get TemplateBk() 'As Excel.Workbook '<< different error messages depending on if "As Excel.Workbook" is included or not
    TemplateBk = fTemplateBk
End Property

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::
'::
':: methods
Public Sub openTemplate()
    Set fTemplateBk = Excel.Workbooks.Open("\\xxx\yyy\zzz.xlsx")
End Sub

Public Sub someMethod()
    Me.TemplateBk.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Normal module:

```
Sub control()

Dim x As clXXX
Set x = New clXXX
x.openTemplate
x.someMethod  '<<<<<<errors here

End Sub
```

I want to only access the private field `fTemplateBk` via the read-only property `TemplateBk` using code such as `me.TemplateBk.  ...`. How do I amend the above so this is possible?

Comment: Missing `Set` in your property Get....

Comment: Also, why use the property within the class? You already have access to the member field.

Comment: @citizenkong - it's a good practice to use the property vs the backing field. Eg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271318/should-you-access-a-variable-within-the-same-class-via-a-property

Comment: @citizenkong I believe within a class's constructor it is fair play to access a private backing field directly but anywhere else good practice is to use setters and getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make that property public and must use Set keyword.

Check the below code and confirm if it works:

```
Private fTemplateBk As Excel.Workbook

Public Property Get TemplateBk() As Excel.Workbook 
    Set TemplateBk = fTemplateBk
End Property
```

Comment: how do I add a Let/Set procedure to run with this Getter?

Comment: Check this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092662/set-property-of-vba-class-with-object-reference

Comment: Thanks for link. I did some research via this book last night and now feel a bit more confident: http://www.amazon.com/Rob-Bovey-Professional-Excel-Development/dp/B00JHX5GVE

Answer (score 1):

Your someMethod should use the private field fTemplateBk as it is private from outside, not from inside.

```
Public Sub someMethod()
    Me.fTemplateBk.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

If you need to use the property from outside, in your normal module you should use:

```
Sub control()
    Dim x As clXXX
    Set x = New clXXX
    x.openTemplate
    x.TemplateBk.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to keep your code as it is, just add the SET in your TemplateBk getter and the code will work. As you can see in the picture, I used your same code with this change and it works.

```
Property Get TemplateBk() 'As Excel.Workbook
    Set TemplateBk = fTemplateBk  'add the SET at the beggining
End Property
```

[image]

Comment: As stated in the question - I want to access `fTemplateBk` via the property `TemplateBk` _even when inside_ - this is good practice. I believe the general `OO` rule of thumb is to only access private backing fields when constructing.

Comment: As the others said, you are missing the Set TemplateBk = fTemplateBk, after that It will work. I have tested and there is no error.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Your code will not error but you should use `Me.TemplateBk.Sheets(1).Activate` within `someMethod` in order that the class follows best practices.